# How to click submit button using clj webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, clojure, webdriver

I want to know how to click submit button after filling a form using clj webdriver. I have used click function `(click "a#foo")` but no use.

```
<a class='ct ct-sec' href='javascript:void(0);' id='submit'>
Submit
</a>
```

That is the code for it.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know clj but what is `(click "a#foo")` supposed to do? If I were to guess, `"a#foo"` is a CSS selector but it reads find an `A` tag with `id=foo` which is not true in this case. You might try `(click "a#submit")`?

Comment: @JeffC I have used (click "a#submit") only but didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If you want to click this `submit` link using clj webdriver](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Taxi-API-Documentation#click), you're doing absolutely correct. But the problem is in this statement `(click "a#foo")` selenium would try to click first found `<a>` element which has id attribute value `foo` while you want to click `<a>` element which has id `submit`.

So in your case there is little bit change in the statement, you should try as below :-

```
(click "a#submit")
```

**Note** :- Basically `a#submit` is the `css selector` expression. [Clj webdriver use to locate an element using `css finder`](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Taxi-API-Documentation#css-finder).

[To learn more about `css selector`, you should follow this `css selector reference`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)